# Factorial ring and its polynomial ring.

Tags: ring-theory

I would like help for the following.

> Show that if $A$ is a factorial ring, then for every irreducible polynomial $P \in A[X]$ is a prime element of $A[X]$. (without using the fact that $A[X]$ is factorial)

> Why is every prime element of $A[X]$ an irreducible.

> Write $P$ as a product of irreductible of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$
> $P=10X^3-30X^2+20X-60$.

For the first, I tried to write what it means for $P$ to be irreducible and showed that $ \forall Q,R \in A[X],$ if $ P=QR $ then $Q \in A[X]^\times $ or $R \in A[X]^\times $. Suppose it is Q that is invertible. We then have $\deg(Q)=0$ and $P$ is associated with $R$, $P=\alpha R$, with $ \alpha \in A$. Then I was thinking of using the decomposition of $ \alpha$ as a product of irreducible elements in $A$. But then I have no idea.

Please correct me if I've written any mistakes or give me some hint !

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:
$$P(X)=2 \cdot 5\cdot(X^3-3X^2+2X-6)$$
What are the possible integer roots of $\:X^3-3X^2+2X-6$?

Comment: I would say 1,2,3,6 or their opposites and we can see that 3 works.

Comment: Their ooposites can't be roots for sign reasons. So you can divide by $X-3$. The quotient will have degree $2$, and if it has no integer root, it will be irreducible.

Comment: Ok so for this one we only had to used the "naive" method. I did the Euclidian Division and the resultat has no integer roots so the result is $P(X)=2*5(X-3)(X^2+2)$ The last factor obviously doesn't have roots in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: That' correct. B.t.w., do you know Horner's method for dividing by $X-\alpha$?

Comment: No i do not know of such method, i just do the regular polynomial division.

Comment: It's a bit faster as we work only with the coefficients. It is also known as *synthetic division*, and is derived from Horner's algorithm for evaluating a polynomial at a given point. You can see details on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method).

Comment: I will look into it. About the first one is my idea going to give me something or am i going in a wrong direct ? 
Thank you !

Comment: If I remember well, the standard proof consists in deriving it from the fact that $K[X]$ (denoting $K$ the field of fractions  of $A$) is a P.I.D., hence we can use Euclid's lemma within $K[X]$.

Comment: Would this be a good idea :
Let $P$ be an irreducible of $A[X]$ we know that it is an irreducible in $K[X]$ as well. 
$\forall Q,R \in K[X]$ such that $P|QR$, $\exists k \in K, kP=QR$, since $P$ is irreducible we have, $Q \in K[X]^\times or R \in K[X]^\times $. Without loss of generality lets say that it is $Q$ that is irreducible. Then we have $Q= \alpha$ for $\alpha \in K$, so $kP= \alpha R$ and $ \alpha^-1 k P=R$ and so $P |R$ which means P is a prime element of $K[x]$ and $Q,R \in K[X]\supset A[X]$ so P is prime in $A[X]$.
Is it something like this ?

Comment: I think my last argument is wrong but we can find $Q_1,R_1$ associated to $Q,R$ such that they are in $A[X]$, i would have to multiply by the common denominator of $Q,R$ in the proof and have the same conclusion i think.

Comment: Your last argument seems correct to me. In the first argument, I wondered why you thought that one of $Q, R$ should be irreducible

Comment: What i thought was incorrect is that $Q,R \in K[X] \implies Q,R \in A[X]$ is not true but from the decomposition of $P$ in $K[X]$ we can easily find $P= \frac{a}{b} Q_1 R_1 $ with $a,b \in A$ and $Q_1,R_1$ primitves polynomials, which is a factorization in $A[X]$. This gives an easy way to go from $P$ prime in $K[X]$ to $A[X]$, i think.

Comment: I agree with you.